# How to fix 'spring is not part of the bundle' when trying to run rails console in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv, capistrano3

I'd like to be able to run `rails console` on an app installed with Capistrano(3).

So, I added `gem 'capistrano-rails-console', require: false` to the gemfile

the following to the deploy.rb

```
server 'ip', port: 2, user: 'user', roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true
```

and the following to the Capfile `require 'capistrano/rails/console'`

The problem is that `cap production rails:console` leads to the following error

```
00:00 rails:console
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails console -e production
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
    2: from bin/rails:7:in `load'
    1: from /_some_path_/releases/20210808154555/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/_user_/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:346:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': spring is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add Spring to the Gemfile.

Can you show your Gemfile?

If you have something like

```
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
```

You can promote it above the block.

Comment: I have it in the development group by default. But as I noted I want to run `rails console` in production. `cap production rails:console` AND as I understand spring is not supposed to be used in production

Comment: So it would need to be in the `production` group, or outside of a group. There is probably a good reason it is not commonly run in the production environment, so there may be some side effects. Alternately (and a better idea), you can remove it from development or suppress it when you start the console. FWIW, Spring has caused me a lot of problems so I prefer not to use it.

Comment: btw `DISABLE_SPRING=true` doesn't work. I had to remove it completely from the gemfile

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after a migration to Rails 6.1. My `bin/rails` looked like this and it caused the same error you had:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
load File.expand_path('spring', __dir__)
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

I had to modify it like that (wrapping the first line in a rescue block):

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('spring', __dir__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```